# How to Update latitude and longitude in service when app is background in react native

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm try to update a location in server every 15 minute in react native. So, how can I do that...

I'm using `react-native-maps` for map api

Comment: Anyone can implement this please help how I can do that in my app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was struggling with the same issue for two days, you have to consider the following points.

1: If you come from native Android (using Java), you must be familiar with the concept of background services, unfortunately, it doesn't support in react-native so far.

2: if you want to accomplish your task you have to do the same as me I mean using an authorized library.

3: after a lot of googling I used [this library](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation), which I think you need to use it.

4: and finally this library is not free for commercial use in android so you must pay for them, it's so easy and so powerful.

Answer (score 5):

```
 componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        position => {
            var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude);
            var long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude);
            var initialRegion = {
                latitude: lat,
                longitude: long,
                latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                longitudeDelta: LONGITUDEDELTA
            };
            this.setState({ intialposition: initialRegion });
        },
        error => {
            console.error(error);
        },
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
    );

    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(position => {
        var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude);
        var long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude);
        var LastRegion = {
            latitude: lat,
            longitude: long,
            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDEDELTA
        };

        this.setState({ intialposition: LastRegion });
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID);
}
```

by this code you can get the user`s location and show it ,you can change the time duration by yourself

Comment: The title says when app is IN THE BACKGROUND and I am pretty sure yours does not. Thought maybe without the componentWillUnmount but no luck.